# Where in The Database does File Usage Data Come From

Tags: 7, files, media

How does data in file/[id]/**usage** get compiled?

From what tables does it determine a use?

Is there a way to track down how/where it gets this data and troubleshoot?
Does it take include revision data?

Comment: I think instead of throwing a bounty on that question you should try to enhance it. Make it relevant to others, make it reproducible, provide context, all that. In the current state it's nearly completely unclear what you're actually asking.

Comment: Yeah, there's absolutely no way to answer this question definitely. You're essentially asking every possible way you could produce bad DB foreign keys and troubleshoot how it could happen. That's too abstract and isn't really Drupal specific.

Comment: I'm simply asking where the revision data comes from. Not too far fetched. It is relevant to others since I've seen this issue unanswered elsewhere.

Comment: Relevant to others means making others think: oh yes, this question indeed needs a good answer. Right now the only correct answer to your question is: revision data comes from the database. Not too far fetched. But I guess this is not what you want. So please help us to help you. :)

Comment: @leymannx This question indeed is relevant to others, and saying in the database is being pedantic but I have adjusted grammar to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This route is provided by the [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) module. See the `hook_menu()` implementation where it's registering a callback for that page: `file_entity_usage_page`.

> ```
> $items['file/%file/usage'] = array(
>   'title' => 'Usage',
>   'page callback' => 'file_entity_usage_page',
>   'page arguments' => array(1),
>   'access callback' => 'file_entity_access',
>   'access arguments' => array('update', 1),
>   'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
>   'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE,
>   'file' => 'file_entity.pages.inc',
> );
> ```

Inside `file_entity_usage_page()` in the `file_entity.pages.inc` file following function from core's `includes/file.inc` gets called which retrieves the information directly from the `file_usage` table.

> ```
> function file_usage_list(stdClass $file) {
>   $result = db_select('file_usage', 'f')
>     ->fields('f', array('module', 'type', 'id', 'count'))
>     ->condition('fid', $file->fid)
>     ->condition('count', 0, '>')
>     ->execute();
>   $references = array();
>   foreach ($result as $usage) {
>     $references[$usage->module][$usage->type][$usage->id] = $usage->count;
>   }
>   return $references;
> }
> ```

Core's `includes/file.inc` file provides the API for handling file uploads and server file management. It also provides a function `file_usage_add()` which gets called every time a managed file gets uploaded and which adds newly added file IDs to the `file_usage` table.

> ```
> function file_usage_add(stdClass $file, $module, $type, $id, $count = 1) {
>   db_merge('file_usage')
>     ->key(array(
>       'fid' => $file->fid,
>       'module' => $module,
>       'type' => $type,
>       'id' => $id,
>     ))
>     ->fields(array('count' => $count))
>     ->expression('count', 'count + :count', array(':count' => $count))
>     ->execute();
> }
> ```

The `file_usage` table gets installed from core upon Drupal installation from `modules/system/system.install`'s `function system_schema()`.

> ```
> $schema['file_usage'] = array(
>   'description' => 'Track where a file is used.',
>   'fields' => array(
>     'fid' => array(
>       'description' => 'File ID.',
>       'type' => 'int',
>       'unsigned' => TRUE,
>       'not null' => TRUE,
>     ),
>     'module' => array(
>       'description' => 'The name of the module that is using the file.',
>       'type' => 'varchar',
>       'length' => 255,
>       'not null' => TRUE,
>       'default' => '',
>     ),
>     'type' => array(
>       'description' => 'The name of the object type in which the file is used.',
>       'type' => 'varchar',
>       'length' => 64,
>       'not null' => TRUE,
>       'default' => '',
>     ),
>     'id' => array(
>       'description' => 'The primary key of the object using the file.',
>       'type' => 'int',
>       'unsigned' => TRUE,
>       'not null' => TRUE,
>       'default' => 0,
>     ),
>     'count' => array(
>       'description' => 'The number of times this file is used by this object.',
>       'type' => 'int',
>       'unsigned' => TRUE,
>       'not null' => TRUE,
>       'default' => 0,
>     ),
>   ),
>   'primary key' => array('fid', 'type', 'id', 'module'),
>   'indexes' => array(
>     'type_id' => array('type', 'id'),
>     'fid_count' => array('fid', 'count'),
>     'fid_module' => array('fid', 'module'),
>   ),
> );
> ```

---

Yes, on `file/%file/usage` not only the nodes get listed where a certain file is being referenced, also node revisions are listed.

[image]

On `file/%file/edit` then you have the option to replace this file on all listed places, and as another option to "Keep (the) original filename", which then replaces the file everywhere it's being used and keeps its former URL intact.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any `/usage` path in core. You must be using a custom or contrib file manager module.

> From what tables does it determine a use?

According to [file_usage_list](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_usage_list/7.x) the file usage info is stored in the **file_usage** table, so I bet the custom or contrib module must be reading from there.